# Parse Javascript Cloud Code Nested Query

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am writing a script on parse.com's javascript cloud code SDK. I am having trouble with the "doesNotMatchQuery" method. 
I have a "class" called activity, this contains a field called movie and a field called fromUser containing the user object of that activity,

[image: Activity Class]

i have a class called movie. I want to get all movies that do not have activity from this user.

[image: Movie Class]

The code I am using(which i know is wrong and doesNotMatchQuery is not the correct method).

```
  Parse.Cloud.define("recommendations", function(request, response) {
  var user = request.user;

  var queryUserActivity = new Parse.Query("Activity");
  queryUserActivity.equalTo("fromUser",user);

  var query = new Parse.Query("Movie");
  query.doesNotMatchQuery("movie", queryUserActivity);
  query.find({
    success: function(results) {
      response.success(results);
    },
    error: function() {
      response.error("movie lookup failed");
    }
  });
}
```

The problem is in the doesNotMatchQuery, only matches against a field, whereas i want it to match against the result objects from the "query", method "doesNotMatchKeyInQuery" comes close but still doesn't offer the ability to match the results of the query with a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below finds the list of the movie objects that you do not want to return via `Activity` table and excludes them from you final `Movie` records.

```
var _ = require('underscore');
Parse.Cloud.define("recommendations", function(request, response) {

var user = request.user;
var queryUserActivity = new Parse.Query("Activity");
queryUserActivity.equalTo("fromUser",user);
queryUserActivity.select("movie");

queryUserActivity.find().then(function(activities) {

    var movieObjIds = _.map(activities, function(activity) {
        return activity.get("movie").id; 
    });
    var query = new Parse.Query("Movie");
    query.notContainedIn("objectId", movieObjIds);
    return query.find();

}).then( function(results) {
      response.success(results);
}, function(error) {
      response.error(error);
});
});
```

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work. I guess its because it would be the movie.objectId
I also tried that query.doesNotMatchKeyInQuery("objectId", "movie.objectId", queryUserActivity);

Comment: I thought so. I updated my answer with a possible solution to the problem

Comment: Thanks Mo Nazemi, that solution works after a couple of edits(syntax errors).